# How do I manually install linux backports

Tags: 12.10, networking, server, backport

I just installed Ubuntu server 12.10 and I am missing the drivers for my ethernet adapter. I have seen this is a common problem for my controller(AR8161) I have downloaded the package `linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.5.0-17-generic_3.5.0-17.1_amd64.deb` on a working machine.

How do I go about installing this package on my Ubuntu machine that does not have a network connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.5.0-17-generic_3.5.0-17.1_amd64.deb
```

Should do the trick when run on the same folder `linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.5.0-17-generic_3.5.0-17.1_amd64.deb` is in. `dpkg` is the backend apt, aptitude and other package managers use to install software.

Comment: is there a certain directory I should copy the package to on the offline machine?

Comment: not really. Its just so you don't have to supply a complete path - any working directory you have permissions to use would work